# How do I get a waiter for a snapshot import task with boto?

Tags: boto3

boto3 waiters come from resources. When I import a snapshot, an 'import-' id comes back. That's not one of the stock resource types, so how can I wait on it?

Comment: Would snapshot_completed be relevant here?
```
>>> ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
>>> ec2.waiter_names
[.., u'export_task_cancelled', u'export_task_completed', u'image_available', u'instance_exists', u'instance_running', u'instance_status_ok', u'instance_stopped', u'instance_terminated', u'password_data_available', u'snapshot_completed', u'spot_instance_request_fulfilled', u'subnet_available', u'system_status_ok', u'volume_available', u'volume_deleted', u'volume_in_use', u'vpc_available', u'vpn_connection_available', u'vpn_connection_deleted']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of at least boto3 1.24.7 there is no waiter for importing a snaphot.
There is an [issue tracking the enhancement request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/282) to add such a feature to the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a boto3 waiter for the import snapshot task.